# checking a string for correct characters in c

Tags: c, string

Is there any easier way to do the following in c?

```
unsigned short check_str(char *str)
{
    while (*str)
    {
        if (!(*str == ' ' || *str == '(' || *str == ')' ||
              *str == '1' || *str == '2' || *str == 'a' ||
              *str == 'x' || *str == 'b'))
              return 0;
        str++;
     }
     return 1;
 }
```

basically it checks a string for any characters other then the ones listed and returns false if it finds one. is there a more simple function?

Comment: You might want to crank up your compiler's warnings settings: you need a `return 1;` at the end of your function to be correct.

Comment: ahh , yeah i just left that out on accident.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want the standard library function [`strspn`](http://www.icewalkers.com/Linux/ManPages/strcspn-3.html):

```
strspn(str, " *(12axb") == strlen(str);
```

It will count characters in `str` until it sees the first one that isn't one of the characters in the second argument. Thus, if it doesn't find any non-matching characters, it will return the length of the string.

A faster way to write the same, though perhaps less clear, is to check for `\0` instead of calling `strlen`:

```
str[strspn(str, " *(12axb")] == '\0';
```

Comment: +1 I had the same `strspn()` idea, but couldn't figure out how to make it efficient. Good call on that.

Comment: str[strspn(str, " *(12axb")] == '\0';
Will return TRUE is the 'str' is actually '\0' ?! no?

Comment: @user457015: good point, there needs to be a check for an empty string here first.

Answer (score 0):

Pavel's answer is definitely what you want for your particular problem, but I just thought I'd add that for the more general problem of validating characters, you can also check for ranges of characters very easily if your strings are ASCII. For example:

```
if (*str >= '0' || *str <= '9') {
   // *str is a number.
}
```

This might be useful if you have a lot of valid characters in a contiguous range. There are a number of standard library functions (e.g. isalpha) that check the common ranges for you.